# JavaScriptException :{} in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`com.facebook.react.common.JavaScriptException : {}`,
I am getting this issue:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-dcP7z0OZd7E/WTD9h58OKmI/AAAAAAAAAMI/7gEpJgcPNcskrJYJhq4OfSUzeRyNvVUQQCL0B/h1280/3584356336441677400%253Faccount_id%253D2

don't know whats getting wrong?

Comment: Could it be related to this issue on github: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13313

Comment: I think so , but I am getting this error before my app getting load.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I put `es2015` preset in my .babelrc file.

- Remove `es2015` preset from .babelrc, use `react-native` instead
- Start the react native packager with `react-native start --resetCache`

Comment: its ```react-native``` only. don't know what id getting wrong, should I have to update ```react-native```

Comment: have you tried resetting cache with `react-native start --resetCache`